# How to DELETE mysql records depending on the JSON array I get from the client?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

What I am doing in the code is basically getting all the ids currently in mysql database. Getting the ids from a JSON array. Comparing them and deleting the ids in the mysql table that are NOT in the JSON array.

```
<?php
```

Getting POST Data (Works)

```
       $test = $_POST["data"];
       $obj = json_decode($test, true);
       $data = $obj["myarray"];
```

First sql query (Works)

```
       $sql3 = "select id from pbs";
       $current_ids= mysqli_query($connection, $sql3)
```

initialize arrays for IDs (Works)

```
       $ids_array= array();
       $ids_array2= array();
```

Get current set of ids from mysql table and putting them in ids_array (Works)

```
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($current_ids)){
             $ids_array[] = $row['id'];
       }
```

Looping over each JSON array $data i.e [{$val}, {$val}, ...]

```
       foreach($data as $val){
```

This is one of the things I'm unsure about. Can I push each id value into and array? i.e:

if $val = {"id": "1", ...} $ids_array2 should have the value "1". If this is correct, I should have an array of new ids that I got from the JSON array.

```
            array_push($ids_array2, $val->id);
```

checks if row is in table by id. If it is, update the mysql row. If it is not, insert a new mysql row (Works)

```
            $check = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `pbs` WHERE `id`='".$val["id"]."'");

           if(mysqli_num_rows($check)==1){
                //Update the row

           }
           else{
                //Insert the row

           }
       }
```

For each item in $ids_array (current set of ids from mysql table). Delete it from table if it is not in $ids_array2 (newset of ids from JSON) where id = $item (Does not work)

```
      foreach($ids_array as $item){
           if(in_array($item, $ids_array2)==0){

                   $sql5 = "DELETE FROM pbs WHERE id='"$item"'";
                   $delete= mysqli_query($connection, $sql5);
               }    
       }

       mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

So what I am trying to do is INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE records depending on the JSON array I get from the client. Thanks!

Comment: And your question/problem is...?

Comment: The Last part does not work. The Delete part. How can I fix it. I know its this line: `$sql5 = "DELETE FROM pbs WHERE id='"$item"'";` But I dont know the syntax etc.

Comment: You wrote all of that, and don't know how to build a string? Perhaps you start by RTFMing? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: @MarcB Bad advice.  Use a parameterized query, don't build a string.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this code:

```
<?php

$test = '{ "myarray": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Harry" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Ron" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Hermione" },
    { "id": 4, "name": "Neville" }
] }';
$obj = json_decode($test);
$data = $obj->myarray;

$id_list = implode(",", array_map(function ($val) { return (int) $val->id; },
    $data));

$connection = mysqli_connect(...);

mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM names WHERE id NOT IN ($id_list)");

foreach ($data as $val) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO names SET id=?, name=? 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name)";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ds", $val->id, $val->name);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

This achieves a few things:

- Delete rows from the database that aren't in the JSON, in one step, without fetching the ids from the database. No need to use `in_array()` for every id value.
- Insert rows that are in the JSON but aren't in the database.
- Update rows that are both in the database and in the JSON.
- Avoid SQL injection by using query parameters. Not for the delete query though, this is safe because I cast the id values to a comma-separated list of integers.
- Avoid loading the entire contents of the database into your PHP app. What if the database grows large enough to exceed your memory limit?

---

Re your comment:

This code:

```
$id_list = implode(",", array_map(function ($val) { return (int) $val->id; },
    $data));
```

gives the same result as this:

```
$id_list_array = [];
foreach ($data as $val) {
    $id_list_array[] = $val->id;
}
$id_list = implode(",", $id_list_array);
```

Note that to access `$val->id`, I had to change the way you decode the JSON:

```
$obj = json_decode($test);
```

You passed the additional argument `true`, which changes the way the sub-fields of `$obj` are created.

Comment: Hi. Thank you, but this doesn't work. Everything in my database gets deleted when I run it.

Comment: I have no idea what you did. I did test this code before posting, and it works fine.

Comment: I believe the problem is coming from `$id_list` I dont think works well. At least not for me. When I run `print_r ($id_list)` I dont get any output. Could please explain what the function is doing please?

Comment: Great, I'm glad to help. By the way, it is traditional on Stack Overflow to thank helpful answers with an upvote, or by checking 'accepted answer.'

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in the query. This will work:

```
   foreach($ids_array as $item){
       if(!in_array($item, $ids_array2)){

               $sql5 = "DELETE FROM pbs WHERE id='".$item."'";
               $delete= mysqli_query($connection, $sql5);
           }    
   }

   mysqli_close($connection);
```

or use a single `DELETE` query:

```
   $deleteIds = [];
   foreach($ids_array as $item){
       if(!in_array($item, $ids_array2)){
           $deleteIds[] = $item;
       }    
   }

   $sql5 = "DELETE FROM pbs WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $deleteIds).")";
   $delete= mysqli_query($connection, $sql5);
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you, but this doesn't work. Everything in my database gets deleted when I run it.