# With this code, how can I delete records from MySql table that are not in my posted JSON Array?

Tags: php, mysql

I am posting a JSON array like:

```
[ { "id": 1 },{ "id": 2},{ "id": 3 },{ "id": 4 } ]
```

It all goes wrong at the `$data = $array->myarray` part, I get:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object on line 12.
```

When I search for the error and read the info on it I feel no closer to resolving the issue. What is happening there exactly?

Here is my code:

```
require('dbConnect.php');

$test = $_POST['jsonarray'];

$array = json_decode($test);

$data = $array->myarray;

$id_list = implode(",", array_map(function ($val) { return (int) $val->id; }, $data));

mysqli_query("DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id NOT IN ($id_list)");



echo $test;

//echo $id_list; 

//var_dump $obj;
print_r($array);
print_r($data);
```

I believe also that only one parameter for mysqli_query is needed, if the server conection details are already known, correct?

Comment: If it's an array, why are you treating it as an object? And you should check the manual for your second question.

Comment: Exactly!  And where does that mysterious myarray  key come from?

Comment: I am basing my code on this question which has been very useful to a degree: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271937/how-to-delete-mysql-records-depending-on-the-json-array-i-get-from-the-client . Sorry my php isn't as good as yours.

Comment: ^^ presuming your follow the rest of that answer, to fix the issue with your json just do `$data = json_decode($test);` and get rid of the `$data = $array->myarray;` line, also you should be checking if the json is valid before doing any queries.

Comment: The SQL is fine. The problem is that you left out the first argument to `mysqli_query()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lawrence Cherone's comment and Barmar's answer I solved my issue like this (I also made my MySql more secure) :

```
$test = $_POST['jsonarray'];

$data = json_decode($test);

$id_list = implode(",", array_map(function ($val) { return (int) $val->id; }, $data));

//mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM test_table WHERE name NOT IN ($id_list)");

$query5 = "DELETE FROM test_table WHERE name NOT IN ($id_list)";
                $stmt5 = $con->prepare($query5) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                $stmt5->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt4->error);
                $stmt5->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I believe also that only one parameter for `mysqli_query` is needed, if the server conection details are already known, correct?

No, this is not correct. The obsolete `mysql` extension worked this way -- the connection argument is last and it's optional, defaulting to the most recent connection that was opened. But `mysqli` doesn't work this way. The connection argument is first, and it's required. So it should be

```
mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id NOT IN ($id_list)");
```

Replace `$conn` with whatever variable you set in `dbConnect.php`.

Answer (score 0):

An array of array can be accessed like:

```
$array[0]["id"]; //using the json supplied
```

mysqli_query requires the connection object as it's first parameter or you can call it using $conn->mysqli_query($query)
see mysqli documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: It's an array of objects.